# ElasticSearch returns items that are too far away when using a geo_distance filter

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, geo, elasticsearch

When I am searching my ElasticSearch documents using a `nested filter -> and -> geo_distance` I retrieve documents which are too far away (and I don't want returned.) You can see the [query](https://gist.github.com/1353821) and a screenshot below of the results (raw results on the left and manually filtered results on the right).

[image]

Here's another copy of the query:

```
{
   "query":{
      "match_all":{

      }
   },
   "filter":{
      "and":[
         {
            "term":{
               "PropertySubType":"Single Family"
            }
         },
         {
            "term":{
               "City":"Los Angeles"
            }
         },
         {
            "geo_distance":{
               "distance":"2.25miles",
               "Location":[
                  34.111583657,
                  -118.324646099
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "range":{
               "BedroomsTotal":{
                  "gte":3
               }
            }
         },   
         {    
            "range":{
               "BuildingSize":{
                  "gte":3000
               }
            }
         },
         {    
            "range":{
               "YearBuilt":{
                  "lte":2000
               }
            }
         },
         {    
            "terms":{
               "ListingStatus":[
                  "Active",
                  "Pending",
                  "Closed"
               ]
            } 
         } 
      ] 
   },
   "size":100
}
```

Comment: I think the problem lies somewhere outside ES. ES shouldn't return any results for your query because 1) Location has to be in [lon, lat] format (latitude of -118 doesn't exist) and 2) unless you changed index mappings, "PropertySubType":"Single Family" shouldn't match any records. You were using standard analyzer for PropertySubType and therefore this field shouldn't contain the term "Single Family" (it should contain two terms: "single" and "family" instead). BTW, it would be much easier to help you if you provided a script that reproduces your problem like https://gist.github.com/1097105

Comment: Thanks imotov, it turns out that I needed to use "plane" instead of "arc".

I have also been updating mappings for the indexes so that some fields are mutli_fields which are analyzed and unanalyzed (such as "PropertySubType")

Answer (score 2):

Adding the option "distance_type" and setting it to "plane" fixed this issue. See "distance_type" here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/geo-distance-filter.html

Comment: The above-linked docs say that the `plane` distance type is faster but provides less precision. I wonder why you'd get better distance calculations using the `plane` distance type.